# php - unset variable from variable array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, unset

i want to create a for loop in order to unset the spesific variables in an array. i cant find any answer on the internet. here is my code.

```
$randomnumber=242;
$variables= array('var','var2','randomnumber');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($variables); $i++) {
unset($variables[$i]);
}

echo $randomnumber;
```

output is:

```
242
```

i dont know what am i missing. please help me guys. i want to unset "var1", "var2", and "randomnumber" variables in the array of "variables". output should be "undefined variable : $randomnumber" or smth like that.

Comment: Why should it? `$randomnumber` is not used anywhere in your for loop code...

Comment: i want to unset $randomnumber by using for loop.

Comment: Then just do `unset($randomnumber);` your array and for loop have nothing to do with your `$randomnumber` variable

Comment: on third for loop it should work like `"unset($variables[3])"` > `"unset($randomnumber)"`

Comment: if you have 600 variables to unset, you want to use a for loop :)

Comment: `unset($variables[3])` does exactly do what it says. It unsets the 3rd array element. It doesn't grab the value of the array use it as a variable and then unset that specific variable. If you want to do that you have to write your code differently.

Comment: i was asking about how can i write that code :) `unset(${$variables[$i]});` works great, thanks anyway.

Comment: Your code is outputting normally. You're assigning then echoing without manipulating the variable in anyway, shape or form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
unset($variables[$i]);
```

means

> unset value with key `$i` from array `$variables`

If you want to unset a variable with name `$variables[$i]` then you should use [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$randomnumber=242;
$variables= array('var','var2','randomnumber');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($variables); $i++) {

    // variable variable syntax here
    unset(${$variables[$i]});

}

echo $randomnumber;
```

Comment: YOU ARE INCREDIBLE. thank you. i was searching for that for a long time!

Comment: `count` is O(1) like taking a value from a variable, isn't it?

Comment: @u_mulder Still you count the array 3 times instead of just once and store the value in an array.

Answer (score 0):

simpler and faster solution:

```
$randomnumber = 242;
$variables = ['var', 'var2', 'randomnumber'];

foreach ($variables as $variableName) {
    unset($$variableName);
}
```